Custom unmarshall func for explicitly nested type struct
I have a explicitly nested type struct like this:
type Communicate struct {
    Sender struct {
        Command string `json:"command"`
        Info  string `json:"info"`
    } `json:"sender"`
    Payload []struct {
        PayloadRow map[string]interface{} `json:"payloadRow"`
    } `json:"payload"`
}

and I would like to write custom unmarshall function for that explicitly nested "PayloadRow" type.
I know, that I can put "PayloadRow" type separately, outside the Communicate type, but does Go make it possible to define function without doing that?
I was trying some ways, like:
func (payloadRow *PayloadRow) UnmarshalJSON(anyPayload []byte) error {
func (payloadRow *Communicate.PayloadRow) UnmarshalJSON(anyPayload []byte) error {

but there are errors every time...

Go allows method declarations for named types only. PayloadRow is NOT a named type, it's NOT even a type, it is the name of a struct field. Just like you can't declare methods on variables, you can't declare methods on fields. What you want is not possible.

this can solve your problem I think
type Communicate struct {
    Sender struct {
        Command string `json:"command"`
        Info  string `json:"info"`
    } `json:"sender"`
    Payload []struct {
        PayloadRow json.RawMessage `json:"payloadRow"`
    } `json:"payload"`
}


Thanks, it was valuable to learn new things and practice them. Anyway, I will lean towards the second solution, because as I read - json.RawMessage is dedicated to json streams (and since I'm just learning Go, I listen to the manual :-) )


func (payloadRow *Communicate.PayloadRow) UnmarshalJSON(anyPayload
[]byte) error {

Go does not allow defining methods on nested types like Communicate.PayloadRow directly. Methods can only be defined on named types.
In this case, PayloadRow is an anonymous field within the struct type inside the Communicate type, so you cannot define methods on it directly.
we should define PayloadRow outside of Communicate and then define the UnmarshalJSON method on that named type. For example:
type PayloadRow struct {
    // Fields...
}

func (pr *PayloadRow) UnmarshalJSON(anyPayload []byte) error {
    // Unmarshalling logic...
}

type Communicate struct {
    Sender struct {
        Command string `json:"command"`
        Info  string `json:"info"`
    } `json:"sender"`
    Payload []struct {
        PayloadRow PayloadRow `json:"payloadRow"`
    } `json:"payload"`
}

I hope this will help.

Yes, this works, thank you. I was looking for a way to "compress" the syntax, but maybe that's not always the best way :-)
